# Special characters in the input of hunspell are treated as space

Tags: windows-7, command-line, spell-check

I am testing hunspell in the command line with a swedish dictionary.
The input in the interactive mode replaces all special characters (for example å ä ö) with blanks before spell cheching.

```
Hunspell 1.3.2
sjögräs
& sj 15 0: SJ, aj, dj, sk, s, j, sej, sju, sjö, sjå, sa, se, ej, st, si
& gr 15 3: ge, g, r, ger, gir, gro, gör, grå, går, gry, er, nr, dr, go, kr
*

sj gr s
& sj 15 0: SJ, aj, dj, sk, s, j, sej, sju, sjö, sjå, sa, se, ej, st, si
& gr 15 3: ge, g, r, ger, gir, gro, gör, grå, går, gry, er, nr, dr, go, kr
*
```

As you see, the prompt's encoding is working, showing å ä and ö both in the input and the output.

Piping gives the same result:

```
echo sjögräs | hunspell -d sv_SE
```

I have tried to give different options to hunspell, including `-i UTF-8`, `-i UTF-16`, and keeping the aff file's `SET ISO8859-1`. Nothing worked.

The same thing happens with french:

```
C:\Users\gauthier>echo résultat | hunspell -d fr-moderne
Hunspell 1.3.2
*
& sultat 2 2: sultan, rAcsultat
```

with in addition problems with the output.

I compiled hunspell in MinGW and moved the resulting needed files to somewhere in my path, but I don't think that this information is very relevant.

How do I make hunspell recognize special characters on its input?